# How to retrieve array variables in a class

Tags: php, arrays, class, object

I'm new to OOP and very confused about it. A class that collected user info from database based on the ID passed though:

```
class user {

    public $profile_data;
    public function __construct($profile_user_id) {
        $this->profile_data = user_data($profile_user_id, 'id', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'admin');
    }

}

$profile_data[] = new user(1);
```

How do I get all the variables in the array? How do I echo out the `username` for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply try this.

```
class user {

        public $profile_data;
        public function __construct($profile_user_id) {
            $this->profile_data = user_data($profile_user_id, 'id', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'admin');
        }

    }

    $userObj = new user(1);
    $profileData = $userObj->profile_data;
    echo $profileData['username'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your user_data function is returning an associative array of data, you should be able to access the fields using as such:

```
$profile = new user(1);
echo $profile->profile_data['username'];
```

As in Lighthart's example, it would be good practice to create private variables, with functions to access them.

Another option would be to implement the ArrayAccess interface (http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) Using this interface, you would be able to use your object similarly to how you use an array. That is, you could use:

```
echo $user['username'];
```

As a starting point, you could try something like:

```
class user implements ArrayAccess {
  private $data;
  public function __construct($profile_user_id) {
    $this->data= user_data($profile_user_id, 'id', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'admin');    
  }

  public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
    // Do nothing, assuming non mutable data - or throw an exception if you want
  }

  public function offsetExists($offset) {
    return isset($this->data[$offset]);
  }

  public function offsetUnset($offset) {
    // Do nothing, assuming non mutable data - or throw an exception if you want
  }

  public function offsetGet($offset) {
    return isset($this->data[$offset]) ? $this->data[$offset] : null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you have given probably won't work for what you are trying to accomplish.  It is not clear what function userdata does.  Revised:

```
class User {
    private $id;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $email;
    private $admin;

    public function __construct($id, $username, $password, $email, $admin) {
        $profileData = user_data($profile_user_id
                                ,'id'
                                ,'username'
                                ,'password'
                                ,'email'
                                ,'admin');
        $this->id       = $profileData ['id'];
        $this->username = $profileData ['username'];
        $this->password = $profileData ['password'];
        $this->email    = $profileData ['email'];
        $this->admin    = $profileData ['admin'];

    }

    public function getId(){ return $this->id; }
    public function getUsername(){ return $this->username; }
    public function getEmail(){ return $this->email; }
    public function getAdmin(){ return $this->admin; }
    public function setAdmin($admin){ $this->admin = $admin; }

}
```

The variables are set private.  Only the user object should have access to the data directly.  However, other objects might want to retrieve the data, which is why there are 4 public get functions.  getPassword was omitted because you probably don't want that one publicly available.  Also, it is concievable you might set a new admin, so a public setter function was added as well.  you would instance the new user (that is, take the class and make a real example of it) thusly:

```
$user1 = new User(1);
```

And during usage you would echo these variables by:

```
echo $user1->getUsername();
```

Please accept my apologies for not directly answering your question, but that example is headed for trouble.

Comment: The `user_data` function fetches data from the database. How would I incorporate where those variables go?

Comment: Editted based on my best guess of the code.  You'll have to post the user_data function if my edits are not sufficient.